# Herkunft der Redewendung "aus die Maus"?

Tags: idiom

Lässt sich dieser Spruch irgendwie erklären?

Mir käme in den Sinn, etwa es ist abend und es ist Zeit die Sendung mit der *Maus* *aus*zuschalten - "Aus die Maus" halt.

Comment: _Armin_ oder _Christoph_ von der  Sendung sagen das bei vielen Folgen sogar zum Schluss.

Comment: Aber die Sendung kommt nicht abends sondern sonntags um elf. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich habe beim Rundfunksender SWR1 in deren [Sprichwortkunde](https://www.swr.de/swr1/rp/programm/aus-die-maus/-/id=446640/did=17492916/nid=446640/w68f25/) folgende Erklärung gefunden:

> Bei "aus die Maus" hat man an die Alltäglichkeit der Nager bis weit ins 20. Jahrhundert zu denken. Dieser Plage begegnete man mit Katzen, Gift und einer erstaunlichen Vielfalt an Fallen. Bei sichtlichem Erfolg erfolge die zufriedene und gereimte Redewendung "Aus die Maus!" Von hier aus übertrug man sie auf die Forderung nach einem definitiven Ende oder auf die Feststellung eines Endes.

Quelle: "Dr. Essigs kleine Sprichwortkunde" von [Dr. Rolf-Bernhard Essig](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolf-Bernhard_Essig).